# jQuery UI datepickers get date and day name on one click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using `datepicker` by jQuery UI to get the full date and day. But now I want to do that with just *one click* on calendar. Here is my Example code:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var pickerOpts1 = {
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    };
    var pickerOpts2 = {
        dateFormat: "DD"
    };
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker(pickerOpts1);
    $("#datepicker2").datepicker(pickerOpts2);
});
</script>
```

The fields are simply:

```
<form  method="get" action="check.php">
    <p>date: <input type="text" name="dateH" id="datepicker1" /></p>
    <p>day: <input type="text" name="dayD" id="datepicker2" /></p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: The problem is I want to make fullday and day appear in the input box at the same time when I choose at calender.

Comment: WOW..!!!! @FerhadOthman thanks dude... that what i want... work like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/0g4runLb/

```js
$(function(){
  var pickerOpts1 = {
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
      onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        $('#datepicker2').val($.datepicker.formatDate('DD', date));
      }
  };
  $("#datepicker1").datepicker(pickerOpts1);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form  method="get" action="check.php">
  <p>date: <input type="text" name="dateH" id="datepicker1" /></p>
  <p>day: <input type="text" name="dayD" id="datepicker2" /></p>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Nice... this is what i want... thanks bro...

Comment: @AmirAmirul Welcome buddy :) Please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example which may help you:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(date){
      var dayNames = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday", "Friday","Saturday"];
      var d=new Date(date).getDay();
      $('#datepicker2').val(dayNames[d]);
    },
    dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'
  })
});
</script>


<form  method="get" action="check.php">
   <p>date: <input type="text" name="dateH" id="datepicker1" /></p>
   <p>day: <input type="text" name="dayD" id="datepicker2" /></p>
   <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```